# How to convert object's attributes in kebab-case to camelCase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, json-api, camelcasing

I'm receiving a json formatted in kebab-case, like so :

```
{name: "田中 太郎", profile-image: "", visit-frequency: "10"}
```

I have multiple objects that I want to display in my template, so I'm using a `v-for`. But I can't figure out how to display `profile-image` or `visit-frequency`, as I obviously can **not** do :

```
<li class="cell" v-for="item in members">
  <img :src="item.attributes.profile-image" :alt="item.attributes.name">
</li>
```

I'm thinking about a loop on my list of objects and rename those attributes, but I feel like there something better than that.

Comment: Could you do `item.attributes['profile-image']`. Sorry I'm not vue programmer but you access kebab-case like this in regular javascript

Comment: Quick answer ~ `item.attributes['profile-image']`, `item.attributes['visit-frequency']`, etc